# Modifying the suffix of a specific range of columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with N number of columns. In this case 25 and would like to change the suffix only from colum variables 15 to 30.

t0 is the dataframe with the 30 column variables

For all the variable 1 to 30, the following command works perfect:

```
t0<-data.frame(a=c(1),b=c(1),c=c(1),d=c(1),e=c(1),f=c(1),g=c(1),h=c(1))

colnames(t0) <- paste( colnames(t0), "Sub",sep = "_")

names(t0)
 [1] "a_Sub"    "b_Sub"        "c_Sub"       "d_Sub"    "e_Sub"  
 [6] "f_Sub"    "g_Sub"        "h_Sub"       "i_Sub"    "ii_Sub"
 [15] "j_Sub"    "k_Sub"       "l_Sub"       "m_Sub"    "n_Sub"
```

Desired output:

```
names(t0)
 [1] "a"    "b"        "c"       "d"          "e"  
 [6] "f"    "g"        "h"       "i"         "ii"
 [15] "j_Sub"    "k_Sub"       "l_Sub"       "m_Sub"    "n_Sub"
```

Any idea how to get this done in R?

Thanks,

Albit

Comment: Try `names(t0)[1:15] <- sub("_.*", "", names(t0)[1:15])`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried this command: colnames(t0[15:30]) <- paste( colnames(t0[15:30]), "Sub",sep = "_") .... But it did not changed the number of any of the variables. The actual dataframe goes from 1 to 155 variables I'm using 30 to keep it practical.. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need `colnames(t0)[15:30] <- paste(colnames(t0)[15:30], "Sub", sep="_")`

Comment: Thank you Akrun!! That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work was due to subsetting the dataset and then get the column names.  Instead, we can directly get the column names of the entire dataset and subset the columns with numeric index

```
colnames(t0)[15:30] <- paste(colnames(t0)[15:30], "Sub", sep="_")
```